# Symmetric Real RV is Equal to the Difference of iid RV

Tags: probability

We can show that if $X, Y$ are real iid random variables, then $X-Y$ is a symmetric random variable (about $0$). Indeed, $$\Pr[0 \leq X-Y \leq a] = \Pr[0 \geq Y-X \geq -a] = \Pr[0 \geq X - Y \geq -a].$$

But is the reverse true?

> If $Z$ is a symmetric random variable (about $0$), are there two random variables $X, Y$ that are real iid such that $Z$ and $X-Y$ have the same distribution?

Comments, suggestions, and solutions are appreciated.